# Standard approach for a split power supply ADC?

Tags: voltage-regulator, adc, voltage-reference, power-supply, split-supply

I'm currently working on a project that will incorporate an AD7124-8 ADC, which as far as I understand can accept true bipolar inputs when provided a split supply. I tried to dig around for an app note or reference design from AD on this, but couldn't seem to find anything.

My questions are

- What is the typical way to go about providing such a supply?
- What parameters do I need to pay close attention to?
- Will I also need to provide a separate split reference?

My current approach is to use a charge pump to convert 3.3V to -3.3v, then an LDO to get -1.8V;

- If this is the right approach, can I use the same LDO on both positive and negative rails?

Comment: Are you sure those voltages are correct for that ADC? Linear regulators cannot reverse polarity. "*separate split reference?*" Read the datasheet.

Comment: I've used a charge pump and (negative) LDO to digitize bipolar signals with only USB +5v. Pick LDOs with high PSRR at the charge pump switching frequency.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I have read the datasheet, it's very unclear and there are no obvious reference designs/app notes for a split power supply at +/-1.8V. My question about the reference was: If I have +/-1.8V for AVDD and AVSS then do I need to find voltage references to supply REFIN1+ and REFIN1-? The datasheet is also painfully unclear on this.

Comment: @Sensors It isn't unclear. You just check the reference voltage required to see if it is actually bipolar or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. The IC supports single or bipolar supplies.
2. You may also define ground as Vdd/2 on a single supply by buffering precision equal R's. Then use a Diff Voltage for 0V using Vbias Ref IN.
3. LDO' are only followers so P and N type are necessary
4. No you can't use the same LDO's and this complexity may be unnecessary, depending on tolerances for 0.00V